# I can't extend my space, how to merge two users to one?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I had one user ubuntu and then it screwed up and I made an other user with 30 gig space then I delete my first user and I ran out of space in my second user and now I want to resize it with live usb gparted but I couldnt access rest of my hard that is root and ext4 drive even unallocated drive, what should I do? what happened if I delete my root drive?

Comment: DId you allocate space manually to each created user and how did you do that?

Comment: Please update your question with the output og gparted and of `df -h`.

Comment: Do you mean (home) partition when you say user?

Comment: From Live Ubuntu run `sudo parted -l` and post results.